# how to handle click event for the custom gwt widget

Tags: gwt, event-handling, uibinder, custom-widgets

I have a my own widget which simulates a multi select list box.
It will have a list of check boxes.

```
  public class MultiListBox extends Composite implements IsWidget
  {
    private static MultiListBoxUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(MultiListBoxUiBinder.class);

    interface MultiListBoxUiBinder extends
        UiBinder<Widget, MultiListBox> {
    }

    public MultiListBox() {
       initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
    @UiField ScrollPanel scrollPanel;
    @UiField FlowPanel flowPanel;

    private final List<CheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
    private final List<String> selectedValues = new  ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void addItem(final String value, final String text){

    final CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(text);
    checkbox.setFormValue(value);

    checkbox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
    {
        public void onClick(final ClickEvent event)
        {
            final CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)event.getSource();
            if(chkbox.getValue())
            {
                selectedValues.add(value);
            }
            else
            {
                selectedValues.remove(value);
            }
        }
    });

    flowPanel.add(checkbox);
    checkboxes.add(checkbox);
}

@Override
public List<String> getSelectedValues(){
    return selectedValues;
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    checkboxes.clear();
    selectedValues.clear();
    flowPanel.clear();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return checkboxes.size();
}

  }
```

I am consuming this in my views like

```
  <my:MultiListBox ui:field="myList"></my:MultiListBox>
```

Now, I wanted to create a onClick handler for this "myList" field in my view like

```
    @UiHandler("myList")
    void onMyListCliced(ClickEvent e) {
         //TODO: handle it
    }
```

Can anyone please guide how to achieve it.

Regards,
Sree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MultiListBox` has to implement interface `HasClickHandlers` (in case of click event).
If you want to allow usage of other events via `UiHandler` there is a bunch of other interfaces in a form of `Has*Handlers`, which you will have to implement on your custom widget.

Comment: Thank you So much for the reply... I added the below method to MY MultiListBox.java class`code'
 @Override
 public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
  return this.addHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
 }
and handled a Clickevent 
 @UiHandler("specialties")
 void onSpecialtyChange(ClickEvent e) {
 }

But I dont get into this method, when I clik the checkboxes in the widget.
The check Boxes will be added dynamically.

Comment: I don't think that I understand what is your problem now. Where did you add `onSpecialtyChange(ClickEvent e)` ?

Comment: oh... please ignore my previous reply.
It doesnt get into onMyListCliced(ClickEvent e)

Actually, the checkbox widgets are getting added dynamically.

Comment: I solved the issue. I modified the addItem() method..

add the line within the checkbox click handler
fireEvent(event);
Thank you so much for your effor jusio